# Open access electric vehicle trip dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, transportation, energy

Are there any open access electric vehicle trip dataset, that contains information about vehicle energy consumption, speed, acceleration, distance or GPS? Used electric vehicles should not be older than 5 years.

Most of the available data is already processed and contains annual statistics about electric vehicle trips.

The data would be used to develop energy consumption model of an electric vehicle.

Comment: found a nice analysis paper but can't find the underlying data... https://rpubs.com/jianlee/ev01_proc_desc